# How to show transparent png in PhpOffice Spreadsheet?

Tags: php, png, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I use standard code for inserting images from s3 bucket to spreadsheet

```
$stamp = MemoryDrawing::fromString($stamp_file);
$stamp->setName('Stamp');
$stamp->setHeight(120);
$stamp->setCoordinates('A2');
$stamp->setWorksheet($sheet);
```

All the examples I found used jpg files, but I need a png.
Problem is artefacts in transparency, like image below.

[image: Stamp with background]

MemoryDrawing's default mime and renderer is PNG, and even if I explicitly specify it, then nothing will change.

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance